# how to open the current path with finder at iterm?

Tags: macos, iterm

Is there any easy way to open current path at finder  when i use the Iterm. It`s terrible to copy the path and paste in to finder path bar everytimes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just run command "open ." this will open current directory in finder.

Comment: this also includes files as well, ``open index.php`` opens ``index.php`` the default code editor

Answer (score 0):

`open` alone did not work for me. To display a file in the Finder without opening I did `open <file_name> -R` (The "-R" flag is necessary to show the file in the Finder without opening it)